# How to extract antonyms from a dataframe and put it in another using wordnet python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nltk, wordnet

I'm trying to get a set of synonyms and antonyms for each column in my data frame, i was able to get the synonyms but the antonym, i wasn't able to, this is my attempt, thank you

```
import pandas  as pd
import nltk.corpus
from nltk.corpus import stopwords, wordnet
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer, WordNetLemmatizer

df = pd.read_csv('healthtapQAs++.csv')
df['unpunctuated'] = df['question'].str.replace(r'[^\w\s]+', '')
df['tokenized'] = df['unpunctuated'].apply(word_tokenize) 
stop = stopwords.words('english')
df['stopped']= df['tokenized'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item 
not in stop])
df['syno'] = df['stopped'].apply(lambda x: [wordnet.synsets(y) for y in x])
df['synonyms_question'] = df['syno'].apply( lambda x:[(y[0].lemmas() 
[0].name()) if len(y) >0 else "" for y in x])
anto = df['syno']
for j in anto.lemmas():
     if j.antonyms():
         df['antonyms'] = j.antonyms[0]().name()
#df['antoyms_question'] = df['syno'].apply( lambda x:[(for j in 
y[0].lemmas() if if j.antonyms()) if len(y) >0 else "" for y in x])
```

and this the error that i get, I'm a total novice when it comes to coding... thank you.

```
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

     AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'lemmas'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i solved it 
By adding this function, that i found on the net, and then using it on my dataframe

```
def get_antonyms(input_lemma):
antonyms = []
for syn in wordnet.synsets(input_lemma):
    for lemma in syn.lemmas():
        if lemma.antonyms():
            antonyms.append(lemma.antonyms()[0].name())
return antonyms
```

afterwards i use it as follows

```
df['antonyms_question'] = df['stopped'].apply(lambda x: [get_antonyms(y) for y in x])
```